# Add image array in existing array node

Tags: arrays, node.js

See my code below.

```
exports.myexports = (req, res) => {

  var arrayname = new Array();
  Hello.find({},function(error,fetchAllHellos)
  { 
      if(fetchAllHellos)
      {
        async.eachSeries(fetchAllHellos, function(Hello, callback)
        {

          var hArr                  = {};
          var image = {};
          hArr['_id']           = Hello._id;
          hArr['myname']        = Hello.name;


           /* Use asyn Parallel method for waiting those functions value */
          async.parallel
          (
            [
                function(callback)
                {
                  fetchingDetails(Hello._id, function(err, fetchAllDetails)
                  {

                    bArr['address'] = fetchAllDetails;
                    async.eachSeries(fetchAllDetails, function(fetchAllDetails, callback)
                    {

                      async.parallel
                      (
                        [
                          function(callback)
                          {
                            fetchingMyImage(fetchAllDetails._id, function(err, wer)
                            {
                                image[fetchAllDetails._id] = wer;
                                callback(err); //Forgot to add
                            })
                          }  
                        ], 
                        function(err)
                        {
                          //console.log(image);
                          arrayname.push(image);
                          //bArr['image'] = image
                          callback(err); 
                        }
                      ); 
                    });

                    callback(err); //Forgot to add
                  });
                } 
            ], 
            function(err)
            {
              arrayname.push(hArr);
              callback(err); 
            }
          )
        }, 
        function(err)
        {
          console.log(arrayname); //This should give you desired result

        });
      }
      else 
      {
        return res.json({"status":'error'})
      }
  });
};



function fetchingMyImage(mid, callback)
{

  UserImage.find({myid:mid},function(error,fetchallImages)
  {
    callback(error,fetchallImages);
  });
}
```

**I want like this array**

```
user
[
  id = 'lkjlk',
  myname = 'helloname'
  address = [
                object,
            ]
  image = [
            myid = image.png

          ]          

]
```

Comment: You are overriding `callback` function in each invocation, which is not a good idea, at least in terms of readability

Comment: There is a syntax error in 2nd `async.eachSeries`. You tried using the array as iterator. See my answer and let me know if it helps you solving the issue.

Comment: Also you never added final callback for the 2nd `async.eachSeries`. Unnecessary use of `async.parallel` inside 2nd `async.eachSeries`.

Answer (score 0):

Made changes in your code. Let me know if it helps you.

Please go through the code and let me know, whether you understood the changes or not.

```js
exports.myexports = (req, res) => {

 var arrayname = new Array();
 Hello.find({},function(error,fetchAllHellos)
 {
  if(fetchAllHellos)
  {
   async.eachSeries(fetchAllHellos, function(Hello, callback)
   {

    var hArr                  = {};
    var image = [];
    hArr['_id']           = Hello._id;
    hArr['myname']        = Hello.name;
    
    //Read doc before you can start using.
    async.parallel
    ([
     function(callback)
     {
      fetchingDetails(Hello._id, function(err, fetchAllDetails)
      {

       bArr['address'] = fetchAllDetails;
       async.eachSeries(fetchAllDetails, function(eachDetail, callback)
       {
        fetchingMyImage(eachDetail._id, function(err, wer)
        {
         image.push({eachDetail._id : wer;
         callback(err); 
        })

       }, function(err)
       {
        console.log(image);
        arrayname.push({images :image});
        
        callback(err);
       });

      });
     }
    ],
    function(err)
    {
     arrayname.push(hArr);
     callback(err);
    })
   },
   function(err)
   {
    console.log(arrayname); //This should give you desired result
                console.log(arrayname.images)// Array of images will be consoled here.
    //callback(err);

   });
  }
  else
  {
   return res.json({"status":'error'})
  }
 });
};



function fetchingMyImage(mid, callback)
{

 UserImage.find({myid:mid},function(error,fetchallImages)
 {
  callback(error,fetchallImages);
 });
}
```